# Debugging IO limitations

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-compute-engine

I am trying to understand IO wait with google cloud SQL under load. I use the D1 plan which is supposed to allow 100 concurrent queries. I don't see any stats about the concurrent queries in my dashboard, but locally I have a 64 thread pool so I can never exceed 64 concurrent queries (well 2 more from time to time). Additionally my IO ops per second peak at 20.

Moving to the a bigger plan helps but only slightly.

And the queries are quite simple - select 1, select small order by random dominantly.

All my 64 threads are stuck on google SQL IO at the socketRead() like this:

```
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:114)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:161)
at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.read(ReadAheadInputStream.java:189)
- locked <5f74f841> (a com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3049)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3492)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4043)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
- locked <7856a45c> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2758)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:894)
- locked <7856a45c> (a com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:732)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CheckValidConnectionSQL.isValidConnection(CheckValidConnectionSQL.java:74)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.isValidConnection(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:1173)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.checkValid(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:461)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.getInvalidConnections(BaseWrapperManagedConnectionFactory.java:999)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.validateConnections(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:870)
at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.validator.ConnectionValidator$ConnectionValidatorRunner.run(ConnectionValidator.java:277)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Can you advise how to understand the bottleneck?

[image: The IO graph]

EDIT:
Also, this is the timeout exception which comes eventually after being stuck:

```
The last packet successfully received from the server was 13,969 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 13,969 milliseconds ago.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor107.newInstance(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3603)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3492)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4043)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.CachedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(CachedPreparedStatement.java:107)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeQuery(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:462)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3503)
        ... 62 more
```

EDIT2: The consumer is a google cloud computing instance, collocated with the DB.

Comment: Are the MySQL connections not used for more than 10 minutes? If yes then what you observe GCE firewall timing them out. Setting the TCP keepalive to something smaller than that should fix that. You can see how to do that here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/docs/gce-access

Comment: I restarted the server multiple time ensuring the connections are fresh seconds before my test and I ran the server under load for a good 1 hour in this failure condition which should have forced whatever lazy inits are needed. Repeated the test few hours apart as well to rule out network glitches. All other network connections work fine. This should not be the problem here.

Comment: Update: it's only a particular query that's taking too long - 8-10 seconds standalone against an idle DB. And concurrent queries of the same type amplify the number so when it gets to 64 it's completely frozen for all types of queries. It looks like "order by rand()" is very slow. If I remove it response time jumps back to 200ms.

Comment: Can you run EXPLAIN on that query? Cloud SQL doesn't perform well for queries that use temporary files.

Comment: I reduced the query to the following "select * from USERS order by rand()". This takes 12 secs on a 7K rows USERS table. If I remove the "order by rand" then the query becomes "select * from USERS" and takes 200 ms. 200 ms is my ping time to the SQL server so it practically takes no time. I use 7K rows to measure the scale of the problem. This issue is reproducible with 1K rows too, because of the additive delay under concurrent load. Adding a SQL limit clause doesn't help. All of this is only for that query.

Comment: EXPLAIN result is this:1 SIMPLE USERS ALL NULL NULL NULL NULL 7801 Using temporary; Using filesort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Using filesort` indicates that a sorting needs to take place. If the amount of data is bigger than `sort_buffer_size` then a temporary file will be created. The temporary files are slow in Cloud SQL so avoiding them is paramount for getting good performance/

The default value for `sort_buffer_size` is 2M. It's a both a global and session variable so it can be change in the queries that requires more memory.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sort_buffer_size';
+------------------+---------+
| Variable_name    | Value   |
+------------------+---------+
| sort_buffer_size | 2097152 |
+------------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Each time the `sort_buffer_size` is too small the `Created_tmp_files` status variable will be incremented.

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Created_tmp_files';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| Created_tmp_files | 663   |
+-------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

More information on `Using filesort` can be found in [Baron Schwartz's post on MySQL Performance Blog](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/). A deep discussion of 'ORDER BY' can be found in [Sergey Petrunia’s blog post](http://s.petrunia.net/blog/?p=24).

I wrote a small program ([mysql-sorttest](https://github.com/razvanm/mysql-sorttest)) to specifically test the sort performance of MySQL.

In the default config (1000 rows) the data fits in the memory (the `Created_tmp_files` is not incremented after the test) so queries are fast:

```
$ ./sort -dsn="root:root@tcp(x.x.x.x:3306)/sorttest" prepare
2014/08/24 12:22:03 Start number of rows: 0
2014/08/24 12:22:06 End number of rows: 1000
$ ./sort -dsn="root:root@tcp(x.x.x.x:3306)/sorttest" run
2014/08/24 12:22:10 Sleep 10s
2014/08/24 12:22:10 Start oneRun
2014/08/24 12:22:20 Done 3000 requests
2014/08/24 12:22:20 Total requests: 300.00/s
$
```

For 5000 rows the data doesn't fit in memory and the speed drops substantially:

```
$ ./sort -dsn="root:root@tcp(x.x.x.x:3306)/sorttest" -table_size=5000 prepare
2014/08/24 12:22:53 Start number of rows: 1000
2014/08/24 12:23:08 End number of rows: 5000
$ ./sort -dsn="root:root@tcp(x.x.x.x:3306)/sorttest" run
2014/08/24 12:23:15 Sleep 10s
2014/08/24 12:23:15 Start oneRun
2014/08/24 12:23:25 Done 91 requests
2014/08/24 12:23:25 Total requests: 9.10/s
$
```

A comment on `ORDER BY RAND()`: as indicated in [numerous places](https://www.google.com/search?q=ORDER+BY+RAND()) it's good to avoid that type of query because it forces MySQL to generate random for every row and then sort that. That is a CPU intensive operation and doing that with enough threads will eventually consume all the CPU (or perhaps hit some other limits in mysqld).